# Dialogflow error: Standard Edition limitation

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I am using Dialogflow free version for intent detection.
I'm sending 170 requests per minute but still get an error saying I've exceeded the limitations of the Standard Edition. (I put in a sleep command for 1 minute after every 170 requests).
The documentation says that there is a limit of 180 requests per minute, other than that there is no limitation for Text Input (My text is *not* greater than 256 characters).
Unsure why I'm still getting this error.
Is there any other limitation of the Standard Edition I should be aware of?

The error I get:

```
Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED
    details = "Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Standard Edition text query operations' and limit 'Standard Edition text query operations per minute' of service 'dialogflow.googleapis.com'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be about how fast you are making the requests. If all of them happen in a very short amount of time you may be getting a higher rate of request at some point, even though you haven't exceed the quota in requests. You may avoid this by distributing the requests in blocks of fewer requests and  ensuring that there is more than a minute, you can try with a few more seconds (beware that most of the sleep functions work in ms) between the blocks of requests that sum up to 170 or 180.

As far as the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/quotas) states there are not additional limitations rather that the ones listed.

To double-check the quotas consumption and see if you are reaching another limit, you can go to the GCP console under the menu: AIM & Admin -> Quotas

Select "All quotas" related to the Dialogflow service and verify. For more detail there is documentation for "[Viewing your quota](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#viewing_your_quota)".

Comment: Thanks, will try out. I rechecked the quota and didn't find anything new. Also, I made sure that the sleep function is for one minute.